# "Сто грамм" или "сто граммов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image]

И все-таки, как правильно: "сто грамм" или "сто граммов"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форма 100 грамм не только допустима, но в устной речи и предпочтительна в связи с тенденцией языка к укорачиванию, "экономии средств языка". Возможны оба варианта, но если без цифры -предпочтителен вариант с -ОВ, с цифрой - нулевое окончание.
Шутка насчёт филологов - подтрунивание над строгим соответствием нормам языка, а они меняются, разговорные нормы часто становятся литературными, тогда разговор "филологов" выглядит архаично, иногда даже странно.

Comment: Тенденция к экономии объясняет не всё. Посмотрите вокруг, пошарьте по соседству:

- сто *миллионов ампер*: можно ли сказать **сто миллион амперов**? - **сто ватт** или **220 вольт**, скорее всего, не были подвержены укорачиванию, а так и сразу и родились;

- возможно, когда-то мы и будем говорить "пять миллион", но совершенно не могу себе представить **пять литр**, **шесть метр** или **восемь час**. Почему здесь не действует тенденция к экономии?

Comment: Эта тенденция действует при вариантности, тогда выбор за экономичной формой.Некоторые названия единиц измерения в любых значениях родительного падежа множественного числа используются без окончания. Это слова ампер, ватт, вольт, аршин, герц. Слово гектар, наоборот, во всех случаях следует употреблять с окончанием -ов: сто гектаров, количество гектаров.

Comment: Здесь спросили о правильности, а не о том, почему верны оба варианта. Если рассуждать на эту тему, нужно вспомнить о появлении счётной формы. Она - следствие того,что математическое отвлеченное мышление вторглось в общий язык и изменило систему числительных, лишив их отчетливых форм имени, оторвав их от структуры существительных и прилагательных, как в европейских языках, где имена числительные (до определенного предела) — это абстрактные показатели выраженного в цифрах числа однородных предметов: sept cents = 7 cents; fünf Kinder= 5 Kinder, математич. показатель при названии предмета.

Comment: Как, например, слово минус: Пять  минус три. Что такое "минус"- сущ.? Нет, ни сущ., ни наречие, ни глагол, просто математич. знак. Так и число при существительном - математический знак, поэтому нулевое окончание; родит. падеж счётный совпадает с начальной формой.

Comment: "Минус" - это название знака,  существительное по лексическим и грамматическим признакам. А вот интересна его синтаксическая функция.

Comment: Так и я об этом."Есть свои плюсы и свои минусы" - это сущ. в роли подлежащего, а вот "Пять минус три" - математическое действие, а не собственно предложение в языке. Ой! - тоже не предложение, это слово-предложение, нечленимое, высказывание и т.д., но не предложение, вот и это не предложение, и там нет частей речи, там числа и знаки математики.

Answer (score 5):

Обсуждали мы уже. В  учебниках по культуре речи строгая норма: граммов, допустимо в разговорном стиле (неофициальная обстановка) - 100 грамм. В ЕГЭ - граммов, килограммов.Тенденция к укорачиванию - да. верно. Наверное, позже будет единственно верным вариантом.

Comment: А где обсуждали-то? Ссылочку не дадите?

Answer (score 2):

Сто граммов, килограммов, гектаров...

Answer (score 1):

Сто грамм.
В сочетании с числительными форма "грамм" как минимум допустима.
Зализняк (и не только) относит такие конструкции к особому падежу - "счетной форме".